# Should I use Java or .NET for web development?

Tags: java, .net

Which of these two platforms/ecosystems are better for writing web applications/websites?

I am not interested in language features, but rather in the available tools like: Monorail, MVC.NET, NHibernate, etc. These kinds of tools are usually used to build modern, data-driven, AJAX enabled websites.

Assume the choice of platform is up to you. Operating system does not matter.

Comment: In my case, it's a question of which platform do I like more: Windows/IIS, or *NIX/Tomcat.

Comment: It depends on the infrastructure, architecture requirements, skills of available developers, the functional requirements, time, etc.

Comment: Windows+Tomcat. It leaves open a *Nix "port".

Comment: Voting to reopen; seems like a reasonable question, despite subjectivity.  Should be CW, though.

Comment: Geese, people. I'm asking which of the two ecosystems makes it easier to build a webpage, assuming equivalent knowledge of two said ecosystems. This is not a made up question. My company decided to go with one of these and not the other because 'it is better'. 

I'd like to hear the community's feedback on this, and I seriously don't understand all the negativity.

Comment: Make that website, not webpage.

Comment: @ripper234 But the way you asked it was like asking "Who's better, Kirk or Picard?"

Comment: Then edit the question, don't close it.

Comment: How am I supposed to edit the question to include information relevant to your situation and company?  (I can't edit/close anyway, I don't have enough rep).

Comment: Then comment and say you need more information...

(Thought my question was general purpose, not related to specific requirements but just to those for building a standard modern website).

Comment: You can try to edit your question to also ask about which features each provide that would be beneficial to your company (with more information about the kinds of things your company does. And since some people seem to have a problem with the fact that .NET is a framework and your referring to it as a language (I know what your meaning but some people are chocking on the wordage), you can rephrase that part.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which has your company decided to use? And are ya'll just on windows like everyone is bringing up?

Comment: We use .Net (MonoRail, I think) for the website, and use Java for some specific backend libraries that are available only in Java. It's not a light task connection the two, but it's doable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Neither. It all depends on your personal preference and what you're comfortable with. You'll get the job done with both.

**EDIT**

To more directly address the tools issue you raise after your edit, you can compare things like that fairly directly:

```
+--------------------+------------+-----------+
| Tool \ Environment | .NET       | Java      |
+--------------------+------------+-----------+
| Web framework      | .NET MVC   | Struts    |
| ORM Mapper         | NHibernate | Hibernate |
| Unit testing       | NUnit      | JUnit     |
+--------------------+------------+-----------+
```

...and as a matter of fact, a lot of the tools (NHibernate and NUnit are both examples) originated in the Java world before being ported and utilized in .NET land.

Comment: Are you sure? The tooling/platform/ecosystem/3rd party libs are equally comfortable and expressive?

Comment: .NET MVC is just possilibty, we're actually using Monorail now, I think.

Not being a web developer myself, I can't really ask the specific questions about the frameworks, but what I really wanted to know is how does {.Net MVC, Monorail, ...} compare to {whatever tools are in Java. Struts?}

Comment: Well, you could also use Spring which is available on .NET and Java.  This way, you only have to learn one framework.

Comment: Note that the world is more diversified now three years later.  Spring, JBoss and Java EE have their own web framework.

Answer (score 13):

It depends... which one are you most proficient at? That's the one.

Answer (score 9):

The most important question you need to ask your company is:  Will we use Windows as our future deployment platform only?

If no, then .NET is out of the question :)

If yes, then we can go on - I believe .NET has advantage over Java in terms of tooling.

Comment: Apparently the game changed:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/11/12/opening-up-visual-studio-and-net-to-every-developer-any-application-net-server-core-open-source-and-cross-platform-visual-studio-community-2013-and-preview-of-visual-studio-2015-and-net-2015.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I've used both extensively and these days I'd struggle to recommend one over the other (assuming of course that considerations such as platform, licensing costs and existing team skills are not taken into account).

One thing I would say is that the Java ecosystem is larger and more diverse than the the .Net ecosystem (although the gap is narrowing rapidly). This and the tendency of many .Net users to favour products and frameworks that come directly from Microsoft seems to lead to more "standardization" in the .Net world.

I've joined Java projects where its taken me 2-3 weeks to start to get productive. In one case the build system (Maven), IDE (NetBeans), web framework (Tapestry), O\R layer (something I can't remember and have never used since) were all new to me. From what I've seen you're much less likely to see this in a .Net shop.

All the options in the Java world can be very confusing and it can make it difficult for newcomers to your team to get up to speed. Having said this, once (intelligent!!) decisions are made and standards are in place there is no reason for Java development to be any more or less productive than .Net

Comment: I absolutely agree with Mark.  One downside with Java Frameworks is that you always seem to be learning a new one (and not necessarily because it's better).

Answer (score 2):

it depends on what platform you are hosting on.  I personally prefer .NET, but if I had another environment, I'd use java (if others like PHP/Ruby weren't available)

Comment: I mentioned the PHP/Ruby thing too.  If he's not developing some kind of enterprise app, and doesn't have a Microsoft preference, why not use something more web-oriented.

Answer (score 2):

I like Java. I love eclipse.

However you will always find .NET hosting is much cheaper than java server.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, and you're set on using a one of these two frameworks, there's no reason *not* to use .Net.

Answer (score 0):

For me Visual Studio makes it an easy choice :)

Comment: Don't discount NetBeans and Eclipse.  Both are very capable IDE's.  Granted, Visual Studio is probably better, but it's doesn't have the breadth of features the other two have (plugins created by the community).

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at Groovy and the webframework that is build on top of it: Grails. It is easy to use, simple and yet let's you use the full java stack if you have to.

I don't know about .NET but I would not go for a *Java-Only* solution, that is *any* of the 100+ webframeworks that are out there... Too much boilerplate code, too many abstractions. If you get into trouble and you *really* have to know what is going on under the hood, you could be in trouble...

Comment: But if he does make the leap, he might be better for it.  Especially if he looks into one of the more documented frameworks like Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I think both systems have their strengths.

You can easily bundle a Java web application and deploy it on numerous App Servers (Tomcat, Glassfish, etc.).  Java has a very rich, mature community that feature a lot of great development frameworks and feature-rich IDE's (NetBeans and Eclipse).  The technology is portable, so you're never locked into having to choose an OS.  And the best part is, most of it is free.  Most frameworks in Java are also designed to "place-nice" with each other, so you can actually plug-and-play different features at will (ORM, AOP, IOP Container, etc).  This is not particularly true with .NET, there are not that many free libraries/frameworks to use with the technology (and definitely not many with the adoption levels Java frameworks have).

As a matter of preference, I prefer .NET because I think the development environment is just a little bit easier, and the documentation is pretty consistent (I feel more productive).  This is not to say that Java doesn't have good documentation, it just tends to be hit or miss dependent on project.  In my opinion, Visual Studio is the best development environment; it takes the edge off learning what amounts to a pretty sophisticated website framework.  Unfortunately, it costs a bit of money, and the technology is pretty narrowing to the best patterns and practices Microsoft thinks you should commit to (though they tend to borrow liberally from Java, so it usually works out in the end).

I'm sure more people have things to say about this.  I hope, you are asking this question in the context of writing some business applications, too.  If this is for your own personal website, I would suggest moving to a cheaper (hosting), lighter technology like Ruby or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

2 reason to go for java :-

1. platform independent
2. free (save lot of money for big cooperation)

even if you are not planning to use system in any other platform, cost is very important factor. I will agree, feature wise as of now I can't compare java with .net. dot net has great feature, great tool support but I hope, oracle will provide equivalent solution in future. you can see Java FX as a one step toward this. I also hear that java is secure but didn't find any specific reason for this. Please let me know if not agree .